# How to get name of all email attachments of a particular mail using imaplib, python?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I am trying to fetch all the attachments of email messages and make a list of those attachments for that particular mail and save that list in a JSON file.
I have been instructed to use `imaplib` only.

This is the function that I am using to extract the mails data but the  `part.getfilename()` is only returning one attachment even if I have sent multiple attachments.

The output I want is the list of attachments like `[attach1.xlss, attach2.xml, attch.csv]`.
Again, I can only use `imaplib` library.
I also don't want to have to download any attachment, so please don't share that code. I tried several websites but couldn't find anything that I could use.

```
def get_body_and_attachments(msg):
    email_body = None
    filename = None
    html_part = None
    # if the email message is multipart
    if msg.is_multipart():
        # iterate over email parts
        for part in msg.walk():
            # extract content type of email
            content_type = part.get_content_type()
            content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
            try:
                # get the email body
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
            except:
                pass
            if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                # print text/plain emails and skip attachments
                email_body = body
            elif "attachment" in content_disposition:
                # download attachment
                print(part.get_filename(), "helloooo")
                filename = part.get_filename()
                filename = filename
    else:
        # extract content type of email
        content_type = msg.get_content_type()
        # get the email body
        body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
        if content_type == "text/plain":
            email_body = body
    if content_type == "text/html":
        html_part = body
    return email_body, filename, html_part
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that attachments will have file names; in particular, inline images are often attached without a file name, just like the text parts you are skipping here. Whether something is inline or attachment is sometimes expressed in the `Content-Disposition:` header, but MIME specifies a default which is `attachment` for most types but `inline` for text parts; so in its absence, you have to know the default for the current body part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy; I just had to do this.

```
import re
# getting filenames 
filenames = mailbox.uid('fetch', num, '(BODYSTRUCTURE)')[1][0]
filenames = re.findall('\("name".*?\)', str(filenames))

filenames = [filenames[i].split('" "')[1][:-2] for i in range(len(filenames))]
```

Explanation: `mailbox.uid` will fetch the message (or mail) of a particular uid (num) and will return a byte string with all the data relating to that message.

Now I use `re.findall` to find all the attachment names and then I clean that return value and save it as a list.